# Question about generalized eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Learning about generalized eigenvectors, and am slightly confused by the following:

In my textbook (axler lin alg done right) there is the following definition:

If T is an operator on a vector space V, and a is an eigenvalue of T, then v is callled a generalized eigenvector if $(T-aI)^nv=0$ where n u dim V.

Here is my question: is the above definition equivelent to $T^nv=a^nv$?

I don't think so, since $(T-aI)^nv=(T-aI)^{n-1}(Tv-av)=(T-aI)^{n-1}Tv-(T-aI)^{n-1}av$ which would lead to a total of $2^n$ terms, of type Tv raised to different powers, and a term of the form $a^n$. Am i wrong in thinking that the two statements are not equivelent?

Comment: You are correct. They are definitely not the same. What is true though is that $(T-aI)^{n-1}v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ (with eigenvalue $a$).